# method chaining with polymorphism c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, fluent

Is it possible to write fluent chanining methods that return a derived type?  Consider the following two classes:

```
class Base {
protected:
    std::string mFoo;
public:
    Base& withFoo(std::string foo) {
        mFoo = foo;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
    std::string mBar;
public:
    Derived& withBar(std::string bar) {
        mBar = bar;
        return *this;
    }

    void doOutput() {
        std::cout << "Foo is " <<
            mFoo << ".  Bar is " <<
            mBar << "." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I would then like to build my object and use it like this:

```
Derived d;
d.withFoo("foo").withBar("bar").doOutput();
```

This of course fails since `withFoo` returns a `Base`.  Since all my `with` methods simply set member variables, I can specify the derived `with`s first.  The problem is my builder method (`doOutput` in the example above) would then need to be a separate statement.

```
Derived d;
d.withBar("this is a bar")
    .withFoo("this is my foo");
d.doOutput();
```

My question is whether there is some way for `withFoo` to return an unknown derived type so that `Base` may be used seamlessly with multiple derived classes (after all, `*this` *is* a `Derived`, although `Base` (correctly) is unaware of the fact).

For a more concrete example, I'm writing a few classes to access a REST server.  I have a `RestConnection` class with method `withUrl`, a `PostableRest` class with methods `withParam` and `doPost`, and a `GettableRest` class with `doGet`.  I suspect this is not possible and will probably try cramming a bunch of virtual methods into `RestConnection` but I hate to do that when there are multiple `withParam`s overloaded, some of which don't make sense to include in a GET parameter list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could give Base a template parameter, and Derived pass itself as the parameter when it inherits from Base. Now Base can return a reference to this template parameter.

Comment: You may be interested in Decorator pattern.

Comment: Do you also need runtime polymorphism from `Base` to various derived classes? Also note that generally speaking protected attributes (not methods) are a strong design smell because they allow for easy violation of invariants.

Comment: You are actually have type elision  (Maybe a c-callback some_type function void* object) would just do fine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could utilize [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) here, something like the following, where the derived class tells the base what type it is:

```
class Base
{
    // Abstract/virtual interface here.
};

template <class Derived>
class Base_T : public Base
{
private:
    std::string mFoo;

public:
    Derived& withFoo(std::string foo) {
        mFoo = foo;
        return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base_T<Derived> {
private:
    std::string mBar;
public:
    Derived& withBar(std::string bar) {
        mBar = bar;
        return *this;
    }

    void doOutput() {
        std::cout << "Foo is " <<
            mFoo << ".  Bar is " <<
            mBar << "." << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Mark, do you recommend `static_cast` in this case vs. declaring a virtual base-destructor and using `dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*this)` ? Something [like this](http://ideone.com/ftLrP7), as an example.

Comment: @WhozCraig I absolutely recommend `static_cast` because the inheritance guarantees that the type will be correct in all cases. `dynamic_cast` would add overhead for no additional benefit.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking only because anytime I see a dereference of a cast operation I panic. Also, (unrelated) in your example `Base` is not a template, I *think* you meant `class Derived : public Base_T<Derived>`, but its too early in the morning here for me to know wtf I'm walking about =P (+1 for the CRTP approach)

Comment: This is exactly what I need!  I was already going down the template path, but I haven't dealt with c++ in ages (Java mostly).  The only part I couldn't figure out on my own was the return type for withFoo, but this gives me the expected results.  Any caveats with the static casting?

Comment: @WhozCraig You were right that I missed the `Base_T` inheritance - fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern).

If `Base` is an abstract type (only instantiated in its subclasses) then make it a template taking type name. Your `Derive` will extend the template - e.g. `Derived : public Base<Derived>`. If Base is a concrete type - then you will need to introduce a new abstract class that would be a base type for `Base` and `Derived`.

This way `withFoo` can be templated to return real type.

Answer (score 0):

You options are either CRTP (as Mark B illustrated), or using runtime dispatch on the variable name, eg.

```
Derived d;
d.with("Foo", "foo").with("Bar", "bar").doOutput();
```

this won't be particularly performant, but it's very flexible, and a good match for protocols which can take arbitrary fields.

Comment: This isn't bad actually.  The other answers are more specific to my problem, but I can see this being useful in a variety of situations, especially during the design phase when things may in flux.  I'd +1 this, but don't have the reputation :/

Answer (score 0):

Since your types are not polymorphic (no virtual functions) Base has no knoweledge of Derived.

You can reach you objective esentially with static polymorphism:

```
template<class Derived>
class Base {
protected:
    std::string mFoo;
public:
    Derived& withFoo(std::string foo) {
        mFoo = foo;
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
protected:
 ......
}
```

The drawback is that there is anymore a `Base` class, but as many `Base` instanciation as are the possible derived, hence you cannot anymore have a Base& or Base* pointing to whatever Derived.

If you need a common-base to collect, you need another CommonBase (not templetized) from which Base can derive from.

Another possibility is making Base (the old one) polimorphic by making `withFoo` virtual.
At that point, in Derived, you can override withFoo to return the Derived& covariant type:

```
class Base
{
   ...
   virtual Base& withFoo(...);
   ...
   virtual ~Base() {} //just to make all the hierarchy destructible through base
};

class Derived: public Base
{
   ...
   virtual Derived& withFoo(type arg)
   { return static_cast<Derived&>(Base::withFoo(arg)); }
   ...
};
```

This still embrace the classic OOP paradigm, but adds run-time overhead (the vtables) and has the disadvantage it is based on a feature (covariant return type of virtual functions) not all compilers support.